# How can I prevent Lua/Sol2 from deleting a user type when it was created outside of Lua?

Tags: c++, lua, lua-sol

I've run into an issue where a parameter (a user type) I pass into Lua function from C++ causes a crash when the Lua object is destroyed. Note I am using [Sol2](https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2/tree/main) in addition to Lua.

I discovered this is happening because Lua appears to be creating a copy of the parameter I passed in, and once the lua object is destroyed, it also destroys that copy. However, one of the member variables of that copy is a pointer to another object. Thus deleting it, deletes the pointer held by the original object, and when accessed causes the crash.

Is there anyway around this? Such as not copying the object but using a pointer to it, or not deleting objects not "owned" by lua/sol2.

I've created a sample project to demonstrate the issue.

**LuaWrapper.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <map>

#pragma warning(push, 0)
#define SOL_ALL_SAFETIES_ON 1
#include "sol.hpp"
#pragma warning(pop)

class SharedClass;

class LuaWrapper
{
public:
   LuaWrapper();

   ~LuaWrapper();

public:
   void RunFuncWithSharedClassParam(
      const SharedClass& shared_class);

protected:
   // Returns true if script loaded
   bool LoadScriptIfNeeded(
      const std::string& file_path);

   virtual void RegisterUserTypes(
      sol::state& lua_state);

private:
   sol::function GetFunction(
      const std::string& file_path,
      const std::string& function_name);


protected:
   typedef std::map<std::string, sol::state> LuaStates;
   LuaStates m_lua_states;

private:
   // No copies, do not implement
   LuaWrapper(const LuaWrapper& rhs) = delete;
   LuaWrapper& operator=(const LuaWrapper& rhs) = delete;
};
```

**LuaWrapper.cpp**

```
#include "LuaWrapper.h"
#include "SharedClass.h"

LuaWrapper::LuaWrapper()
{

}

LuaWrapper::~LuaWrapper()
{
   std::cout << "~LuaWrapper Called" << std::endl;
}

void LuaWrapper::RunFuncWithSharedClassParam(
   const SharedClass& shared_class)
{
   sol::function FuncWithSharedClassParam = GetFunction("C:\\Users\\Omega\\source\\repos\\TestingSolution\\x64\\Debug\\LuaFile.lua", "FuncWithSharedClassParam");
   if (FuncWithSharedClassParam)
   {
      FuncWithSharedClassParam(shared_class);
   }
}


// Returns true if script loaded
bool LuaWrapper::LoadScriptIfNeeded(
   const std::string& file_path)
{
   if (!file_path.empty() && m_lua_states.find(file_path) == m_lua_states.end())
   {
      m_lua_states.emplace(file_path, sol::state());
      m_lua_states[file_path].open_libraries(sol::lib::base);

      RegisterUserTypes(m_lua_states[file_path]);

      sol::protected_function_result result = m_lua_states[file_path].safe_script_file(file_path, &sol::script_pass_on_error);
      if (!result.valid())
      {
         sol::error err = result;
         std::string what = err.what();

         std::cout << "LuaWrapper::LoadScriptIfNeeded()" << "Failed to load script:"  << file_path << " - " << what << std::endl;
         return false;
      }

      return true;
   }

   return false;
}

void LuaWrapper::RegisterUserTypes(
   sol::state& lua_state)
{
   lua_state.new_usertype<SharedClass>(
      // Lua Class Name
      "SharedClass",

      // Member Function Binding
      "Print", &SharedClass::Print);
}

sol::function LuaWrapper::GetFunction(
   const std::string& file_path,
   const std::string& function_name)
{
   if (!function_name.empty())
   {
      LoadScriptIfNeeded(file_path);

      LuaStates::const_iterator it = m_lua_states.find(file_path);
      if (it != m_lua_states.end() && it->second[function_name].valid())
      {
         sol::function func = it->second[function_name];

         return func;
      }
   }

   return NULL;
}
```

**SharedClass.h**

```
#pragma once

class SamplePtr;

#include <string>

class SharedClass
{
public:
   SharedClass(
      const int id,
      const std::string name);

   ~SharedClass();

   void Print() const;

private:
   const int m_id;
   const SamplePtr* m_ptr;

   // Don't create copies, only one instance of this specific object (with this m_id) can exist for the entire program.
   SharedClass() = delete;
   // Unfortunately, Lua/Sol is using this to copy (commenting out causes compile errors)
   //SharedClass(const SharedClass& rhs) = delete;
   SharedClass& operator=(const SharedClass& rhs) = delete;
};
```

**SharedClass.cpp**

```
#include "SharedClass.h"
#include "SamplePtr.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

SharedClass::SharedClass(
   const int id,
   const std::string name) :
   m_id(id),
   m_ptr(new SamplePtr(name))
{

}

SharedClass::~SharedClass()
{
   std::cout << "~SharedClass Called" << std::endl;
   delete m_ptr;
}

void SharedClass::Print() const
{
   std::cout << "Shared Classs ID: " << std::to_string(m_id) <<  " (" << m_ptr->m_name << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

**SamplePtr.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class SamplePtr
{
public:
   SamplePtr(
      const std::string& name);

   const std::string m_name;

private:
   SamplePtr() = delete;
   SamplePtr(const SamplePtr& rhs) = delete;
   SamplePtr& operator=(const SamplePtr& rhs) = delete;
};
```

**SamplePtr.cpp**

```
#include "SamplePtr.h"

SamplePtr::SamplePtr(
   const std::string& name) : 
   m_name(name)
{

}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "LuaWrapper.h"
#include "SharedClass.h"

int main()
{
   // Once created, this object cannot be modified (const).
   const SharedClass* sample0 = new SharedClass(0, "Ptr0");

   // Create lua in it's own scope, so it's deleted.
   {
      LuaWrapper lua;
      lua.RunFuncWithSharedClassParam(*sample0);
   }

   // Try to access sample0's pointer and it's deleted at this point (via the LuaWrapper deletion)...
   sample0->Print();
}
```

**LuaFile.lua**

```
function FuncWithSharedClassParam(shared_class)
    shared_class:Print();
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I received a response from the Sol developer, https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2/issues/1340.

Pretty much just need to pass in the pointer for no copy!